# What is meaning of this three lines in App module.ts Angular file

Tags: angular

This is an Angular `appmodule.ts` file

```
<pre>

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { UploadModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-upload';
import { UploadComponent } from './upload.component';
import { UploadInterceptor } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    imports:      [ BrowserModule, HttpClientModule, UploadModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule ],
    declarations: [ AppComponent, UploadComponent ],
    bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
    providers: [
      {
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: UploadInterceptor,
        multi: true
      }
    ]
  })

  export class AppModule { }
</pre>
```

What is the meaning and use of these three lines? What is `useClass` and what is `multi` in `providers`?

```
providers: [
    {
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: UploadInterceptor,
        multi: true
    }
```

I saw this example in an online portal so I want to understand this configuration in provider and the use of this parameters. I saw this example online Angular + telerik file upload example.

Answer (score 1):

It adds a `HttpInterceptor` (`provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS` sets the token, which whom you can retrieve the interceptor from the injector) to you dependency injection container.

`useClass: UploadInterceptor` provides the class that shall be injected. The `UploadInterceptor` is a class that implements the HttpInterceptor interface (https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor).

`multi: true` means that multiple HttpInterceptors can be registered and not only one. If you don't set this, the HttpInterceptor will be a singleton in the providers scope.

You can read all about this topic in the official Angular docs (https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers).